# Profile initialization on second logon

Tags: windows-7, samba, roaming-profile

Every user in my samba PDC network gets a default profile, created by copying over a local modified user profile to the netlogon share. Now when they first logon there is no problem. But on the second logon Windows 7 spontaneously decides to initialize it for quite some time (1-2 minutes). Why is that so and how can I stop Windows from doing that?

Comment: Are the profiles designated as roaming? Are there group policies in effect on the Windows 7 machines? How is DNS configured on the server and the workstations? Are there any events in the event viewer that occur during this time frame?

Answer (score 0):

It is taking bit long it logging becuase it is going to find profile on server. Assign your server IP as DNS on Windows 7 pc. So it will faster able to search server and logging process will be even faster.

Comment: "Assign your server IP as DNS" is unclear; depending on how interpreted, it could be either beneficial or downright harmful.